# Use a list/set/array of values as a hash key

Tags: ruby, hash, graph, set

I'm trying to implement a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph). I'd like to use a (frozen) set as the key to a hash. I'd like to do the following or something like it.

```
set_a = Set.new(["a","b","c"])
set_b = Set.new(["a","b","d"])
set_c = Set.new(["a","b"])
set_d = Set.new(["a","b","e","f"])

set_a.freeze
set_b.freeze
set_c.freeze
set_d.freeze

data = {
  set_a  => [list of vertices],
  set_b.freeze => [list of vertices],
  set_c.freeze => [list of vertices],
  set_d.freeze => [list of vertices]
}
```

However, it's not quite working. Doing:

```
data[some_set.freeze]
```

seems to cause errors.

Comment: `("a","b","c")` isn't a valid data structure in Ruby. What do you want to use (An `Array`, a `Set`)?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Fair point about the `("a","b","c")`, provided more as an example than runnable code. Although, a tuple (python) is just a immutable list. I had a set in mind to avoid dealing with uniqueness/ordering/canonization concerns. I actually used variables here rather than literals.

Comment: Updated question to more accurately reflect what I was trying to do. Looks like I was overthinking things the answer by @spickermann should do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And as long as you don't expose or share the `data` array there is not reason to freeze it.

You could just use instances of [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html) as keys. But you will have to ensure that the arrays are all sorted in the same way:

```
data = {
  ['a', 'b', 'c']      => [1, 2, 3],
  ['a', 'b', 'd']      => [1, 2, 4],
  ['a', 'b']           => [1, 2],
  ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f'] => [1, 2, 5, 6]
}

data[['a', 'b']]
#=> [1, 2]
```

Or as sawa mentioned in the comments: It might make sense to use [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) to avoid ordering the arrays before using with the `data` hash. With `Set` your implementation might look like:

```
require 'set'

data = {
  Set.new(['a', 'b', 'c'])      => [1, 2, 3],
  Set.new(['a', 'b', 'd'])      => [1, 2, 4],
  Set.new(['a', 'b'])           => [1, 2],
  Set.new(['a', 'b', 'e', 'f']) => [1, 2, 5, 6]
}

data[Set.new(['b', 'a'])] # Note that the order doesn't match
#=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: Probably the OP's intention of using a set is to be free from ordering of the elements. When you do it with an array, you have to normalize it in some way; perhaps sorting it is one way.

Comment: Huh, seems my problem may have been overthinking it then. Python requires considering whether the object is immutable or mutable as to if it can be hashed or not. A list cannot, but a tuple can. A set cannot but a frozen set can.